# Physics of the beaker experiment for superfluid helium

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

here is an illustration and explanation of the beaker experiment over superfluid helium:

[image]

So, according to this experiment, can anyone say what is the cause?
I mean the superfluids are disconnected physically (compare with two tanks of fluid which are disconnected or connected through a way) but they tend to  equalize the levels .
what is the basic physics behind it?!!

I mean what causes the Superfluid Helium to somehow feel or understand the difference of the Helium level in the beaker and the bath.
Is there any entangled states to cause or something else?

Comment: I don't know much about this sort of thing, so I won't give an answer per se. But check out the Wikipedia [Rollin film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollin_film) article.

Answer (score 2):

The film on the surface of the beaker forms by condensation from the saturated vapor above the helium bath. This, by itself, has nothing to do with superfluidity. What is speacial about superfluids is that the film, even though it is only a few dozen atomic layers thick, provides a capillary that the superfluid can flow through without resistance.