# Two-fluid model of helium II and beaker experiment, superleaks etc

Tags: condensed-matter, superfluidity

It is an assumption of the two-fluid model that the normal and superfluid components of helium II cannot be physically separated, but surely the [beaker experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189723/physics-of-the-beaker-experiment-for-superfluid-helium), in which only the superfluid component flows through the film (or any 'superleak' situation) provides a way to separate the two components? How does the normal component flow back into the bath?